# Trying to make a simple login system using a dictionary in python

Tags: python

```
def getlogins():
    from requests import get
    url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ezb2661/lol/master/loginstest"
    return get(url).text

logins = getlogins()
logins = logins[:-1]
username = input("Username:")
username = str(username)
password = input("Password: ")
password = str(password)

if password == logins[username]:
    print("Logged in!")
else:
    print("Wrong password or username")
```

Whenever I run this, it does prompt for username and password, but then it says there is an error on line 15 of :

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: There is not a single dictionary in this code.

Comment: @DeepSpace my getlogins() creates a dictionary off of my github source

Comment: Why do you think so? Try `print(type(getlogins())`

Comment: @DeepSpace because I created it in the format for a dictionary? If I did this incorrectly then can you please explain to me how to do it correctly?

Comment: `get(url).text` returns a `str`, not a `dict`

Comment: @n00dl3 can you explain how I can make it into a dict?

Comment: I can't as I get a 404 with the url you provided and you didn"t give any informations about the structure of the document you are trying to access... is it a json, csv or xml, or maybe unstructured plain text ? nobody can guess

Comment: @n00dl3 it is plain text

Comment: @n00dl3 I had the wrong URL for my github because I was testing if changing it to a .json would work, I just changed it back and now you can access it again.

Comment: `get(url).json()` now you have a dict.

Comment: @n00dl3 now it says TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Your login details is neither a dictionary nor a json, please check it {"ezb2661:test"}

Comment: yeah, right, I didn't noticed it

Comment: *DO NOT* mark a question as "solved". If you figured out the answer, write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by fixing my json format to {"ezb2661": "test"} rather than {"ezb2661:test"}, and then using

```
return loads( get(url).text )
```